# CopyRows_Management in ArcPy gives ERROR 000732?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, error-000732

I get the following error when running a CopyRows_Management with Python (ArcGIS 10.1):

```
ERROR 000732: Input Rows: Dataset \MyConnection.odc\MyTable does not exist or is not supported
```

Here is the script that the model builder exported.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Local variables:
MY_DATA = "Database Connections\\MyConnection.odc\\MyTable"
MY_DESTINATION = "C:\\GIS-Shared\\MyData\\MyGDB.gdb\MyTable"

# Process: Copy Rows
arcpy.CopyRows_management(MY_DATA, MY_DESTINATION, "")
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you could have a look at arcpy.testschemalock() and arcpy.Exists() to help out with the debugging process.

Answer (score 1):

Does your MyTable exist?  Also, your MY_DESTINATION variable needs to point to a out table.  Right now you have it just pointing to a geodatabase.  See link below:

[See out_table parameter here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n4000000)

Comment: Sorry - typo on my part.  MyTable does exist on the input side.  What's strange is this script works in a 10.0 environment but does not work in a 10.1 environment.  They made it more difficult to add an OleDB connection so I'm not sure what may have changed from a scripting perspective.  However, this script was generated by the Model builder just to test that the concept still works.

Answer (score 1):

Is MyConnection.odc the server name. I got the same error and the reason for it is because I didn't add .sde extension behind my server name. Check your servername by looking at the server properties->Editor Tracking. The Realm: @ text field is usually the name you should use.